# Rotatate an image like a book with a css3

Tags: html, css

I have an image where the left side is black and the right side is red.
My question: it's possible flip this image like a book in the middle?i would like the left side rotate and the right side stay in old position.
Thanks

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried.

Comment: http://www.turnjs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve a fairly decent effect using the perspective property and a rotate around the Y axis.

For example with markup like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

You would use CSS like this:

```
.left, .right {
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
  float:left;
}
.left {
  background:red;
  transform-origin:100px 0;
  transition:transform 1s;
}
.right {
  background:black;
}
.wrapper {
  perspective:1000px;
  perspective-origin:100px 100px;
}

.wrapper:hover .left {
  transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
```

This particular example applies the transform as you hover over the "book".

Here is a fiddle example including webkit prefixes: http://jsfiddle.net/nAEBF/

Comment: `transition` and `transform-origin` should not be in the `.wrapper:hover .left` but in the `.left` rule.

Comment: @Christoph If you want the book to animate open again when you're no longer hovering then yes, I would agree. But that wasn't really the point of the answer The OP didn't say how he planned to use this, so I just wanted to demonstrate the properties that were required. I thought it would be clearer to keep them all in one place.

Comment: Because you argue with clearness: pseudoclass rules like `:hover` should always contain only those changes which really *do* change, which is not the case for the transition and the origin. These are static values and thus should be placed in the base rule. Also (regarding your fiddle) the standard conform declaration should always come last, so all `-webkit` prefixed stuff should come before their unprefixed equivalents.

Comment: @Christoph If you really feel the answer can be improved by moving those properties, feel free to edit it. I won't mind.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, is it possible that you could clarify your question? It's hard to tell what you're asking when you say 'flip this image like a book in the middle'. Do you mean you would like the black on the right side and the red on the left? Also, does this need to happen on a webpage, when clicked or hovered over?

For any kind of transformations, you would want to use the [CSS3 transform property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).
For example:

```
div
{
    -ms-transform:rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    transform:rotate(7deg);
}
```

Don't forget to set browser prefixes.

Comment: fyi: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: like James Holderness solution http://jsfiddle.net/NDtcY/  .Sorry but i have some difficult to explain the problem in english.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a functional pure css flip book exists, or I never found it.
You'll find a few experiments, like [this one](http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-page-flip-effect) or [this one](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/cssplay-peter-rabbit.html), which are nice, but only parts of th full work.

Anyway, you can do it with some JS library, I'm thinking about [TurnJS](http://www.turnjs.com/#).